# Set default value in angucomplete

Tags: angularjs

I am using angucomplete-alt to show dropdown search. Its working fine.But in one case I want to set its value from controller.
I tried

```
 $scope.selectedCustomer.title = $scope.customerList[1].businessName
```

& also

```
$scope.selectedMerchant = $scope.merchantList[1]
```

But the both didn't work.
In the angucomplete-alt documentation its written that there is two way binding. 
Can any one help me out in displaying default selection..

Comment: r u sure that your array has data???

Comment: yes. When i select this using drop down its showing the correct data.

Comment: Please set up a fiddle or a plunkr.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if you ever found an answer to this but I thought I would share how I achieved this.

```
<angucomplete-alt id="owner"
placeholder="user@example.com"
pause="400"
selected-object="subscription.EmailAddress"
initial-value="{{subscription.EmailAddress}}"
```

Initial value accepts a string value, using angular syntax I was able to generate this from the controller using curly brackets.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I was using angucomplete-alt along with [ui-bootstrap's modal](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal) I tried a lot, ended up doing this:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$broadcast('angucomplete-alt:changeInput', 'myType', myTypeVal);
}, 200);
```

..and the html was

```
<angucomplete-alt id="myType" placeholder="My Type"
                    pause="400" selected-object="myTypeSelectedFn"
                    remote-url="/searchMyType"
                    remote-url-request-formatter="searchMyTypeFn"
                    search-fields="name" title-field="code"
                    input-class="form-control form-control-small"
                    match-class="angucomplete-highlight"
                    name="myType" minlength="1" field-required="true"
                    field-required-class="alert-danger"
                    text-searching="Fetching.." auto-match="true" 
                    ng-model="modifiedMy.type"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on your controller:

```
$scope.example = {
    text: 'Somethings'
};
```

On `initial-value` of `angucomplete-alt`:

```
initial-value="example.text"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite late but I recently came across angucomplete-alt.
I suggest is to use native JS combined with angucomplete-alt.

You can use **clear-selected="true"** provided by angucomplete-alt and set a timeout of about 200 ms and update your input's value taking its id:

The clear-selected="true" will clear your input on selection and then you can change the input's value from controller.

document.getElementById('ex1_value').value = 'customValFromController';

I used this while I wanted to set something different in the search textbox from what was displayed in the dropdown result list.

Worked for me :) .

Answer (score 0):

We need to pass object reference instead of string to initial-value.

```
<angucomplete-alt id="selectProductTypeName" 
                                placeholder="Search Product Type" 
                                pause="100" 
                                selected-object="vm.selectedProductType" 
                                local-data="vm.productTypeNameList" 
                                initial-value="vm.initialProductType" 
                                search-fields="name" class="angu-form-control" 
                                title-field="name" 
                                minlength="3" 
                                input-class="form-control form-control-small">
                            </angucomplete-alt>
```

initial value in the controller should be

```
vm.initialProductType = { name: response.data[0].product_type};
```